# How to get exit code from subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python

With the code below, `p.returncode` is always `None`. According to the [`Popen.returncode` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode), this means that the process hasn't finished yet.

Why am I not getting an exit code?

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

cmd = ['echo','hello']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
try:
    # Filter stdout
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        # Print status
        print(">>> " + line.rstrip())
        sys.stdout.flush()
except:
    sys.stdout.flush()

print 'RETURN CODE', p.returncode
```

Please note: The reason why I'm reading each line separately is because I want to filter the output of other, long-running, processes in real-time and halt them based on certain strings.

I'm on Python 2.7.5 (CentOS 7 64-bit).

---

### Solution

Thanks to the answer posted by @skyking, I can now successfully capture the exit code like this, using `Popen.poll()` (`Popen.wait()` deadlocked my process):

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time

cmd = ['echo','hello']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
try:
    # Filter stdout
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        # Print status
        print(">>> " + line.rstrip())
        sys.stdout.flush()
except:
    sys.stdout.flush()

# Wait until process terminates (without using p.wait())
while p.poll() is None:
    # Process hasn't exited yet, let's wait some
    time.sleep(0.5)

# Get return code from process
return_code = p.returncode

print 'RETURN CODE', return_code

# Exit with return code from process
sys.exit(return_code)
```

Comment: BTW, you can use `iter(p.stdout, ...)` instead of `iter(p.stdout.readline, ...)`

Comment: @zondo Not sure about Python 2, but in Python 3 you can definitely also iterate directly over `p.stdout` without need for `iter(...)` - maybe you would have to set `universal_newlines=True` for that in the `Popen` constructor though...

Comment: @ByteCommander: That's true (Yes, also in Python 2), but the second argument to `iter` isn't quite as easy to implement.

Comment: @zondo `for line in iter(p.stdout):`, `for line in p.stdout` and `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):` all work the same. No need for 2. argument to iter, if passing something supporting iteration, aka an iterable. The 2 argument form is for passing callables (which `p.stdout` is not, it is a file object). Also `iter(p.stdout) is p.stdout`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the linked to documentation

> The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and indirectly by
>    communicate()). A None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.
>
> A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (Unix only).

You have not called `poll` or `wait` so `returncode` won't be set.

On the other hand if you look in to the source code for fx `check_output` you see that they are directly using the return value from `poll` to examine the return code. They know that the process has terminated at that point because they have called `wait` earlier. If you don't know that you would have to call the `wait` method instead (but note the deadlock possibility noted in the documentation).

Normally the program will have terminated when you've read all of stdout/stderr, but that's not guaranteed and that may be what you're seeing. Either the program or the OS can close `stdout` (and `stderr`) before the process actually terminates and then by just calling `poll` immediately after you've read all the output from the program might fail.

Comment: No matter what I do I can get this to work with `poll`. But it does work fine with `wait`.

Comment: @fredrik I managed to get that behavior too with some effort. I guess that `stdout` and `stderr` gets closed before the program actually terminates and your python program gets to call `poll` before the other program terminates.

Comment: I think I found a way to get `p.poll` to work as `p.wait` did give me deadlocking. I'm posting my full code at the end of my question.