# Running a secondary script in a new terminal

Tags: python

When running a secondary python script:

- Is it possible to run a `subprocess.Popen`, or `subprocess.call` or even `execfile` in a new terminal? (as in simply a different terminal than the current terminal where the script is run).
- Alternatively, if before running my program (main), I open two terminals first, can I then point the secondary script to the second terminal? (so somehow getting the ID of open terminals, and then using a specific one among them, to perform the subprocess).

An example, two subprocesses to be run, `first.py` should be called first, only then the second is called, `second.py`. Because the two scripts `first.py` and `second.py` are interdependent (as in `first.py` goes to wait mode, until `second.py` is run, then `first.py` resumes, and I don't know how to make this communication work between them in terms of subprocesses.)

```
import subprocess

command = ["python", "first.py"]
command2 = ["python", "second.py"]
n = 5
for i in range(n):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(command2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
        output = p.stdout.readline().strip()
        print output
        if output == 'stop':
            print 'success'
            p.terminate()
            p2.terminate()
            break
```

*Framework (Ubuntu, python 2.7)*

Comment: What do you mean by 'in a new terminal'? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The question you link to says nothing about terminal windows. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DisplayName I'm trying something like `subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)` where `command=["python", "test.py"]` but I get "'module' object has no attribute 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE'
". Apparently CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE only works for windows

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code there.

Comment: Related: [How can I open two consoles from a single script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19479504/4279) (consider providing GUI instead or look at the code with `x-terminal-emulator`)

Comment: Related: [Execute terminal command from python in new terminal window?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19308415/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want something like

```
subprocess.call(['xterm','-e','python',script])
```

Good old `xterm` has almost no frills; on a Freedesktop system, maybe run `xdg-terminal` instead. On Debian, try [`x-terminal-emulator`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32547/how-to-launch-an-application-with-default-terminal-emulator-on-ubuntu).

However, making your program require X11 is in most cases a mistake.  A better solution is to run the subprocesses with output to a log file (or a socket, or whatever) and then separately run `tail -f` on those files (in a different terminal, or from a different server over `ssh`, or with output to a logger which supports `rsyslog`, or or or ...) which keeps your program simple and modular, free from "convenience" dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I m very close with your suggestion, great stuff. Both terminals open and the scripts start running, but how can I now monitor their outputs, `output = p.stdout.readline().strip()` does not seem to work anymore, since now they are in separate terminals

Comment: A more useful approach might be to start a simple program to receive and print the output from your main program in a separate terminal, or even just log to a file, and run a regular `tail -f` on the log file in a separate terminal.

Comment: oh I see, sounds reasonable! How do I receive the output from subprocess p now that it's in xterm?

Comment: Don't run the subprocess in an `xterm`.

Comment: The point is to make this work with xterm... As i wanted the subprocesses to be in different terminals.

Comment: @user929304 you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596354/how-to-get-exit-code-from-subprocess-popen) which is how you can filter the output from `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: Once you run your subprocess in a terminal, I don't think there is a way to capture its output. Updated this answer with a suggestion for a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [`tmux`](https://tmux.github.io), you can specify which target you want the command to run in:

```
tmux send -t foo.0 ls ENTER
```

So, if you've created a tmux session `foo.0`, you should be able to do:

```
my_command = 'ls'
tmux_cmd = ['tmux', 'send', '-t', 'foo.0', my_command]
p = subprocess.Popen(tmux_cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, unfortunately I m not using tmux. Any alternatives come to mind?  CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE is not an option sadly as that's only for windows machines

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `tty` of the terminal window you wish the command to be carried out in:

```
ls > /dev/ttys004
```

However, I would recommend going for the tmux approach for greater control (see my other answer).